# How to add Dynamic Data Web site into a Existing Web Project

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, asp.net-dynamic-data

I developed a web site it's online now. Web site has stores and news. When i am developing I don't have much time so i generated a CMS with Dynamic Data Website now i have 2 web sites.

First it was ok because i upload photos with ftp and writing paths to cms but now i have to use cms to upload photos the problem is virtual directories are different i can't write to Website' s folder.

I tried to add my cms to Website project (Add Existing Project) But how can i use both of them any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to review this [Walkthrough: Adding Dynamic Data to an Existing Web Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668188%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) from MSDN.